# How to search in the first part of a string stored in database

Tags: sql, xml, oracle

I have very large xml messages stored in a database. I do a search like this:

```
select * from table where column1 like '%<Sample system="SYSTEMNAME"%'
```

The select takes a LOT of time since it reads through all xml messages along with their huge contents which may or may not contain a match.

My question is: Is there a way to only read the **first part** (fixed length maybe? how?) of the xml messages? Assuming that the first match ALWAYS appears within a fixed length of **the beginning of each xml message**. So if no match is found in the beginning of an xml message, the query should skip the message instead of read through the rest of it.

Thanks!

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: Check if your database system has built-in support for XML data. You might be able to use XPath searches.

Comment: Oracle SQL developer @MartinKlinke

Comment: As you are using Oracle you should take a look at the [Oracle XML DB](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/database-technologies/xmldb/overview/index.html). Maybe it helps to use XMLTYPE for your column1. Just take a look at the documentation (depending on the exact version of Oracle you are using). E.g. for 10g this is a [good entry point](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/appdev.101/b10790/xdb09sea.htm#i1006756)